# Openni_Kinect problem

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ubuntu running ros. I installed Openni_Kinect from the command "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect"

and now I tried this command to test if everything is working, roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch

and the error that I get is "[openni_camera] is not a package or launch file name"

any help welcomed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33569/openni_kinect-problem/) by [mlandergan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2136/mlandergan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mlandergan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2136/mlandergan/) on 2012-05-09**:
I followed the steps that you gave me and everything seems to be working. Is there a way to check? and I then went and tried to install openni_kinect again but I get this error

**Comment by [mlandergan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2136/mlandergan/) on 2012-05-09**:
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-electric-common : Depends: yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev but it is not going to be installed
ros-electric-openni-kinect : Depends: ros-electric-image-common (= 1.6.1-s1328510857~oneiric) but it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your environment is not set up correctly. The package `openni_camera`  installs to `/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera`, and that directory is apparently not on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable. Follow [these steps](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu#electric.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup) to fix this.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1